# Is it safe to unplug the phone while USB Debugging is turned on?

Tags: android

I am developin with Eclipse on an Android device. Each time I want to install the new version of the app on the device I need to connect it, enable USB Debugging, install the app, disable USB Debugging, unplug the device (optional). I was wondering if it was safe to just unplug the device without disabling USB Debugging. After all, the device is not mounted, right? But there is the adb, talking to it. It would be much more convenient to be able to do that. Does anyone know if it is safe or unsafe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can unplug the device. You should, however, unmount your sdcard first if you mounted it.

I plug & unplug it numerous times a day as the USB is my main way of charging the device, unless the battery is extremely low, then I use a wall charger.

Also, I never turn off usb debugging, since its the only way adb can recognize the device when it is plugged in via usb.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but, in my case I cannot use my device to install applications and at the same time mount the SD card... so it does not matter in my case, I just plug and unplug without fear :D

Comment: Yeah, I can't either, but I have apps to SD enabled. I meant in general, if the sd is mounted, before you unplug, unmount. I never even mount mine, I wrote Droid Explorer (http://de.codeplex.com) so I didn't have to mount :) shameless plug ;)